# Address decoder design and memory tables (recommended books)

Tags: digital-logic, decoder, addressing

i have been self studying and i encountered with an exercise of address decoder design, i have seen videos and i have searched in this book "Digital design by M. Morris" which is the one im using for studing digital design but it doesnt explain how to approach to this kind of decoder. I would like to be capable to that myself without look any videos so thats why i wonder where i can find this information, do anyone know in which book may i learn how to design this kind of decoders.

The address decoder that im trying to do have the next requisites

X is low active in the range 00 to 0F

Y ..... 10 TO 2F

Z ..... 30 to FF

E is the enabled input which is low active too

Comment: Why don't you simply lay out a table? We used to have to deal with exactly this kind of thing all day long in the 1970's (and early 1980's.) Eventually, we had programmable logic devices that made it possible to put most of the stuff in a single IC (nice.) But this isn't at all hard. I'd recommend, book-wise, that you look to books written in the 1970's -- perhaps something from Don Lancaster? (I think he had a two-volume set that covered this stuff.) Also, there were plenty of magazine articles on this in the later 1970's and early 1980's, as more and more hobbyists got into the fray.

Comment: Isn't this the table you want:$$\begin{array}{cccccccc|ccc}
\text{A}_7 & \text{A}_6 & \text{A}_5 & \text{A}_4 & \text{A}_3 & \text{A}_2 & \text{A}_1 & \text{A}_0 & \text{X} & \text{Y} & \text{Z}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x & x & x & x & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & x & x & x & x & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & x & x & x & x & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0&0&1&1&x&x&x&x&1&1&0\\
0&1&x&x&x&x&x&x&1&1&0\\
1&0&x&x&x&x&x&x&1&1&0\\
1&1&x&x&x&x&x&x&1&1&0\\
\end{array}$$(**E** is easily added.) So many times have I wire-wrapped something like this.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, ill search for  Don lancaster book.

Comment: i forgot to ask, how can i interpret the address given and make the table from them. i know hexadecimal system but why A0, A1, A2 and A3 are in "dont care" state

Comment: They are, because you don't need to examine them (at all) in order to work out the values of **X**, **Y**, and **Z**. They are not relevant. You can see this from your address ranges that you specified. (Or, you should be able to see why, anyway.)

Comment: oh i see it now, the last doubt i have is related to the last 3 last combination of z, when A4 and A5 are careless, the range for z are from 30 to FF, so why is important to put in the table the last 3 combinations if in theory, if A7 to A4 are greater than 3, z will be active low, it would be innecesary to put those combinations, or in either case, why dont put more combinations, like 0101 (A7, A6, A5, A4).....im sure theres something i cant see, could you iluminate me please.

Comment: now i really see it, thanks for the explanation, A4 and A5 doesnt change form 30 to FF so they "dont care".

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have put a little thinking time in, here's a suggestion to consider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f07nYF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's (4) OR gates, (3) NOR gates (use one as the inverter), and (1) AND gate. Three 7400 series packages to achieve.

This is by no means the only way. (You could, for example, use three 7402 packages and only have to buy that one part, but the longest propagation delay would be longer.) Still, that's yet another way. (Unless I made a gross mistake I'm quite capable of making.)